# Excel VBA: For loop vlookup for each cell in a given column across two sheets

Tags: vba, excel

Basically,I want to go through cells in a specific column, look to see if it fits an attribute in two possible other worksheets (which is denoted by an "x" in that database's column).

If it contains/has that attribute (result of the vlookup is "x"), then paste the value of the original cell into a different cell.

I want to do this for two attributes for each row. Therefore since I have to search 2 worksheets for 2 possible attributes, I have 4 If/Then statements inside the loop.

I put in "counters" for the two attributes so that if I find an item in the list that has an attribute, I make sure that if I find another item later, it's inserted in the row below it instead of overwriting it.

My code runs without surfacing an error but it's not generating any results. I apologize for my amateurism and appreciate your patience!

```
Sub ASSESS()

Dim counterF As Integer
Dim counterS As Integer
Dim cell As Range
Dim Ret As String

'These are counters to start logging the desired cells in rows 6 and 10, respectively, depending on if it fit attribute F or S

counterF = 6
counterS = 10

For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C14:C64")

    Ret = CStr(Application.VLookup(cell, Worksheets("Activities").Range("B2:U1000"), 13, 0))

    If Ret = "x" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counterS, 3) = cell
        counterS = counterS + 1
        Ret = ""
    Else
    End If

    Ret = CStr(Application.VLookup(cell, Worksheets("Song List").Range("B2:U1000"), 13, 0))

    If Ret = "x" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counterS, 3) = cell
        counterS = counterS + 1
        Ret = ""
    Else
    End If

    Ret = CStr(Application.VLookup(cell, Worksheets("Activities").Range("B2:U1000"), 12, 0))

    If Ret = "x" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counterF, 3) = cell
        counterF = counterF + 1
        Ret = ""
    Else
    End If

    Ret = CStr(Application.VLookup(cell, Worksheets("Song List").Range("B2:U1000"), 12, 0))

    If Ret = "x" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counterF, 3) = cell
        counterF = counterF + 1
        Ret = ""
    Else
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide a smaller set of sample data?

Comment: Yes! Sheet1 is the "form" where for each activity/song listed below, I do a vlookup of what's in green and search Song List and Activity List for a matching entry, if that entry has Summative or Formative with an "x", then I want to copy what's in Green on Sheet1 into the Formative or Summative space above in Sheet1. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IWneGsuByLeNxm76hznzLhD2zzq-wDLuhZTX6zU9cTA

Comment: Right away I can see that your lookup data in column "C" on "Sheet 1" will never match with a `VLOOKUP`. The `VLOOKUP` function is intended to be used with a single-word lookup value into a column of data with other single words. Even if this were to be stretched to multiple words, you have way too much data to compare in column C for this. You're going to need another method to create unique lookup data in order for your comparison to work.